# Measuring distance with Wi-fi and Bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, wifi, arduino-yun

The goal of my project is to discover devices with Wi-Fi or Bluetooth turned on (not connedcted anywhere) and measure the distance between those devices and my search devices. The search devices will be some Arduino-like devices which would have Wifi/BT turned on or they could have Wifi hotspot enabled on them.  I'd like to now if it is possible to measure the distance from my search device to the unconnected device. I googled this issue and I found that I can use either RSSI or Triangulation but I don't know whether these solutions apply to my problem. Furthermore I'd like to know if it is possible to discover neareby devices that have GSM turned on and measure the distance to my search devices just as I'd like with Wifi and BT.

Comment: Sounds more like an engineering question. OT for SO

Comment: I don't think so. Because you need to gain the information from the network packets, that would lead you to measure the distance or position.